# Dapper Extension LIKE operator returning results in reverse order while matching string

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-core, dapper, predicate, dapper-extensions

I am using Dapper Extension method GetByPredicate and passing the predicate value with Like operator.

`Predicates.Field<Entity>(row => row, Operator.Like, $"%{string}%")`

But while matching the string pattern it is returning results in reverse order, eg:
if the sql table contains rows having 'test1' and 'test2' string then for a given string 'test', it is returning results as test2 and test1.

Wondering why it is returning in reversed order.

Comment: What makes you think there should be any particular order in the first place

Answer (score 1):

Relational databases usually do **not** guarantee order in which rows are returned. If you want you rows returned in specific order use `order by` clause for this purpose.